# Staying in in London Heathrow Airport overnight?

Tags: accommodation, airports, london, lhr

*FIRST TIME TRAVELER*
Traveling from Phoenix AZ > London > Barcelona Spain.
In London there is a 17.5 over night layover. 
I am planning on using this time to explore the city. 
Can you stay in the airport over night? Or would it be better to book a room?

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7419/where-should-i-stay-in-london-with-an-early-heathrow-departure?rq=1

Comment: and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6740/7-hour-layover-in-lhr-enough-time-to-visit-london-for-a-couple-of-hours?rq=1

Comment: The other answers are good, I can add a few points but first -- just to check -- are you flying into and out of Heathrow? I'm guessing the Phoenix flight goes to LHR but to Barcelona could go from somewhere else -- depends on the airline.

Comment: You *have* asked a lot of questions, and the idea on this site is to ask one question per post,as it makes it easier for future readers to find answers to their similar questions.  If possible, please do have a read of the [help] and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

Can confirm from my personal experience today, there is a No. 1 lounge in Terminal 3 where you can stay overnight in Heathrow for £60 that includes sleeping pod, shower and some food.

Not the best option, but decent if you have visa issues or really early morning flight

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for sharing your experience.

Comment: You must be flying out of terminal 3 though

Answer (score 5):

You can certainly stay in the airport.  [A friend detailed his 24 hours that he spent in Heathrow](http://www.thetravellingeditor.com/my-24-hours-in-heathrow-night/).

Of course, whether it's better or not is up to you.  You'll probably get a better night's sleep in a hotel, but some people can sleep anywhere.  I've slept in a variety of airports, or at least attempted to - some are better than others.  Some have quiet corners, some are crowded, and others have security stopping you sleeping there.

You can always use [sleepinginairports.net](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/) as a guide for your decision, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more comfortable stay at Heathrow there are many hotels at Heathrow airport : http://www.heathrow-airport-guide.co.uk/hotels.html

Comment: and boy are they EXPENSIVE.

Comment: I didn't check the location of this hotel.... But would it need a visitor visa or is it airside?