# Connecting flight in Heathrow

Tags: connecting-flights

I am a Phillippine passport holder, on my returm from Brazil to the Philippines, I will have a connecting flight in Heathrow. It is less than 24 hours but next day flight. April 13, 4 pm, I will arrive  in Heathrow airport and leave tomorrow at 12 nn. I plan to sleep in the airport. Will any type of Visa be needed?

Comment: But there is a hotel inside the airport, Terminal 3 has Aerotel opened last year.

Comment: @Hanky Panky Not sure why you’re so certain of this when it’s contradicted by answers on this site https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20890/staying-in-in-london-heathrow-airport-overnight/72739